# how to lay out cast of characters using dramatist?

Tags: dramatist, screenplay

Is there an option for laying out the cast of characters like at the start of a script for a play using the `dramatist` package? If so, how does one do it?

I had written the following code with mention of characters using `\Character`

```
    \begin{document}

\book*{The Delhi Case}

\Character[Hercule Poirot]{POIROT}{poi}
\Character[Ivan Anderson]{ANDERSON}{and}
\Character[Mr. Jesmond]{JESMOND}{jes}

\scene[.-- Kent]

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Sitting Room in Mr. Jesmond's House\\\poi, \jes
    \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\poispeaks
And so, we meet again, Mr. Jesmond. It is rather tiring.\\
\jesspeaks
\direct{laughingly} It rather is, isn't it? Now, for the case --\\
```

So, I just want to lay out the cast of characters including Hercule Poirot, Mr. Jesmond, and Ivan Anderson.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\DramPer`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}

\begin{document}

\Character[Hercule Poirot]{POIROT}{poi}
\Character[Ivan Anderson]{ANDERSON}{and}
\Character[Mr. Jesmond]{JESMOND}{jes}

\DramPer

\scene[-- Kent]

\StageDir{
    \begin{center} Sitting Room in Mr. Jesmond's House\\\poi, \jes
    \end{center}
}

\begin{drama}

\poispeaks
And so, we meet again, Mr. Jesmond. It is rather tiring.
\jesspeaks
\direct{laughingly} It rather is, isn't it? Now, for the case --

\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

[image]