# Spacing between paragraphs and lists

Tags: spacing

Good morning, everybody.
I'm really going crazy to get a correct code to reproduce what you see in the picture (made with Word). Can someone help me? Thank you.[image: Spacing]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There are several packages that are intended to make it easy to produce drama scripts, see https://www.ctan.org/topic/drama-script.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529109/how-to-lay-out-cast-of-characters-using-dramatist and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529286/are-there-commands-for-entrances-exits-and-exeunts-while-employing-the-dramat for the `dramatist` package - which is however quite simple and a bit old, you may have better results with one of the other packages from the page linked above.

Comment: I'd seen and tried those packages before, but they weren't right for me. Each one of them has so many features that I don't need. I would like to reproduce the layout I posted, without using specially created packages.

Comment: Good morning. I'm interested in this command-character code. You can simplify it by removing **linewidth** parameter?

_\newcommand\character[1]\par\everypar{\hangindent=0.3\linewidth\hangafter=1}\parskip=0.667\baselineskip plus
2pt\large\makebox[0.3\linewidth][r]{\MakeTextUppercase{\1}:\hskip0.1\linewidth }}_.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a list making environment, so that it will break nicely at page boundaries, unlike approaches that use, for example, `tabular` environments.

The optional argument to `mylist` is the indent width (default 1in).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
%\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\let\svitem\item
\newenvironment{mylist}[1][1in]
{%
  \def\mylistindent{#1}%
  \renewcommand\item[1][---]{\svitem[{\makebox[\mylistindent][l]{##1}}]}
  \begin{description}[leftmargin=\mylistindent,labelsep=0pt]%
}{%
  \end{description}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}[.8in]
\item[JIM]\lipsum[4]
\item[ROBBIE]\lipsum[2]
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Steven. But if I enter a longer name, for example "MANZAREK" the character name invades the line text.

Comment: @masfur  That is what the optional argument is for...make the value as big as needed for the particular list you are constructing.  Also, you can change the default `1in` value, as well.

Comment: Very good, Steven. Now I try! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not give the faintest information what you tried and what exactly you want. So, here is just a wild guess at what could be a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lp{0.7\textwidth}}
JIM         & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \\
ROBBIE      & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \\
MANZAREK    & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \\
JOHN        & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}
```

Next time, I would recommend you provide a working minimal example and a clear statement of what you want to achieve and where the problems lie.

Comment: You're right. I've been reading so many Latex tutorials and now I'm really confused. I'm a drama writer and I've always written my own scripts with Word, without getting what I want well. I think using Latex can achieve my goal.

Comment: I followed the instructions of this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204198/new-commands-with-text-align) First I was excited, but then I saw that the code is too difficult!